# armv7: stmb does not take pc

Tags: arm, armv7

I have a library written in C mixed mixed with some assembly for ARM. It used to be compiled for armv6. Now I am trying to upgrade it to armv7. However, there is an interrupt handler which has the instruction `stmdb sp!, {pc}` which is not allowed in armv7. What would be an equivalent instruction on armv7? I tried `str r15, [sp, #-4]!` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's specific limitations regarding the use of `PC` in the reg list for `PUSH` and `POP` instructions, depending on the operation mode, see:

[ARM Instruction Set Reference, `PUSH`/`POP`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Babefbce.html)

Specifically, in Thumb[2] there *is* no `push {pc}` operation (which is the same as saying there's no `stmfd sp!, {pc}` operation - `push` is mapped to `stmfd sp!`).

So if you're compiling your kernel code (why else do you have/need an *interrupt handler* if it's not kernel code), check whether you're compiling a Thumb-2 kernel.

That said, you're saying you encountered a `stmfd sp!,{pc}` instruction - you're sure that's not a typo ? `stmfd sp!,{lr}` (and its sibling, `ldmfd sp!, {pc}` - here `PC` is present) is normal / fully legal and often required / encountered in both ARM mode and Thumb-2 mode. But that actually *is* the purpose of saving the *program counter* to the stack ? What can one do with that that wouldn't be achievable in other ways ?

Comment: I don't see why one would push pc onto the stack in an interrupt handler. When the push statement is executed, pc points at the push statement (or actually 4 bytes after it).

Comment: @Sven that's exactly what I said ?! This might be a _porting artifact_; on 32bit x86, the only way to read the program counter is to push it to the stack (via `call` to ... the next instruction) and directly afterwards pop it off into a register. No such weirdness needed on ARM, hence I asked, "sure that's not a typo ?".

Answer (score 2):

"armv7" is rather generic. What's the actual chip you're using? Are you compiling for ARMv7-M? Try `PUSH {PC}` then. Though I expect that won't be the only issue you will run into. I think you should post some snippets and describe in more details what specific environment you're porting to.